# pointers to a multidimensional array in classes

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get to the bottom of an error, I wonder if you could help please?  I'm having a bit of an issue with array pointers at the moment.  I have three classes, one parent, and two children so to speak.  One of the children has a 2D array of type struct, and I'm trying to access the elements of this from the other child.

I was wondering, is this code valid with the correct format/syntax for my array pointers?
OChild1 creates and fills out the 2D array, I'm saving a pointer to that in Parent, and passing that pointer to OChild2, and then plan on using the contents of the array for further processing.

```
struct BOARDTILE
{
    float fPosX;
    float fPosY;

    BOARDTILES()
    {
        fPosX = 0.0f;
        fPosY = 0.0f;
    }
};

class CChild1
{
    public:
        BOARDTILE BoardTileArray[18][18];

    CChild1()
    {
    }

    writeBoardTileArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 17; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 17; j++)
            {
                BoardTileArray[i][j].fPosX = (float) i * 5.0f;
                BoardTileArray[i][j].fPosY = (float) j * 7.0f;
            }
        }
    }
};

class CChild2
{
    public:
        BOARDTILE (*pBoardTileArray)[18][18];
        float fPosX;
        float fPosY;

    CChild2()
    {
    }

    void readBoardTileArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 17; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 17; j++)
            {
                fPosX = (*pBoardTileArray[i][j]).fPosX;
                fPosY = (*pBoardTileArray[i][j]).fPosY;
                cout << fPosX;
                cout << fPosY;
            }
        }
    }

};

class CParent
{
    public:
        BOARDTILE (*pBoardTileArray)[18][18];
        CChild1 OChild1;
        CChild2 OChild2;

    CParent()
    {
        OChild1.writeBoardTileArray();
        pBoardTileArray = &(OChild1.BoardTileArray);
        OChild2.pBoardTileArray = pBoardTileArray;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store address of a two dimensional array, you would need a pointer to pointer,

**Without typedef:**
You would declare a member pointer as:

```
BOARDTILE (*pBoardTileArray)[18];
```

and then in the constructor, you would write:

```
    pBoardTileArray = OChild1.BoardTileArray;
```

But as you can see it makes the code complex. Using `typedef` can simplify it:

**With typedef:** (Recommended way)
With `typedef` you can write the following in the global scope:

```
typedef BOARDTILE BOARDTILE_ar18_t[18];
```

and then you can declare member pointer as:

```
BOARDTILE_ar18_t* pBoardTileArray;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So, would I need to write the line above
"BOARDTILE ( * pBoardTileArray)[18][18];"
as BOARDTILE ( * * pBoardTileArray)[18][18];
instead?
Or perhaps "BOARDTILE* ( * pBoardTileArray)[18][18];"?

If I declare it as BOARDTILE**  pBoardTileArray;
I seem to get a conversion error with the line:
pBoardTileArray = &(OChild1.BoardTileArray);

Would you have a link to a page where I could learn more about this please?

Comment: Or what about... BOARDTILE (*(*pBoardTileArray)[18])[18]; ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.  My only problem now is working out how to read the contents of the 2D array once the pointer to it has been passed to the other object.
I'm using the version without the typedef at the moment if that makes any difference?  I think I'm slowly beginning to understand the concept of this, but it's definitely a slippery topic.  I think the hard part to grasp is that the array is a set of pointers to begin with.

Comment: I'm attempting to access the array using the lines:
    fPosX = (*pBoardTileArray[i][j]).fPosX;
    fPosX = (*pBoardTileArray[i])[j].fPosX;
    fPosX = (*pBoardTileArray)[i][j].fPosX;
or
    fPosX = *pBoardTileArray[i][j].fPosX;
But none of these seem to work.

Comment: If I consider the pBoardTileArray to be a pointer to one of the dimensions in the array, I've also tried creating a new 2 Dimensional Array, called BoardTileArrayTwo[18][18] within CChild2, and tried using the line:
    fPosX = BoardTileArrayTwo[(*pBoardTileArray)[i].nSomeInt][j].fPosX;
To my surprise this compiled.  Is this the correct way of doing it?  The program still crashed though, but if I'm going in the right direction, this will definitely help.

Comment: Sorry, no, this wouldn't work, would it?  I'm creating a new 2D array at a completely new location there.  I'm afraid I'm at a loss as to how to refer to the location of the original 2D array.

Comment: What about creating a 1d array called BOARDTILE boardTileArrayComp[18]; and then using that as the other half of the array? So:
fPosX = *pBoardTileArray[i][boardTileArrayComp[j]].fPosX;
?

Or maybe it would have to be the other way around, so:
fPosX = *pBoardTileArray[BoardTileArrayComp[i]][j].fPosX;

Or would I have to create a 2d array in CChild2 as BOARDTILE BoardTileArray2[18][18]; and then the line fPosX = *pBoardTileArray[BoardTileArray2[i][j]].fPosX;

Comment: Okay, after a bit of investigating, I think I should be able to use it simply as:
`fPosX = pBoardTileArray[i][j].fPosX;`
For some reason this is crashing with an error that the expression, "pBoardTileArray[i][j].fPosX", cannot be evaluated.  Checking my code, the BoardTileArray is definitely declared and set up with values before the pointers are passed, so this should work in the same way as accessing the Array normally?  I am also only trying to access position 8, 8 at the moment where is goes up to 18, 18, so I am staying within the array's memory scope?

Comment: Okay, I finally have a it working.  Thank you very much.  I would upvote you if possible, but I need 15 rep before I can do that.